# Can I get the full pull request text in a Github merge commit?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Let's say I have a pull request on github. I've spent a tonne of time on it and so enter a long, meaningful description for the PR explaining exactly what happened and why:

```
Immanentises the eschaton.

This eschaton is righteously immanentised by to rapidly
frobnicating the plurglewhatsits.
```

I then merge the pull request and it's done.

Then, when I look at my git log, I see this:

```
Merge pull request #19284 from davidgiven/whadjamacallit

Immanentises the eschaton.
```

Only the first line makes it into the merge commit; the meaningful body which I put so much time into writing is lost.

(Yes, it's still available via Github, but it's not in the *repository*, which is what I care about.)

Is there a way to configure github to copy the entire pull request description into the merge commit?

Comment: I don't think you can make GitHub do this. You can make command-line Git do this easily, using the `merge.log` configuration item.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to configure github to copy the entire pull request description into the merge commit?

No, as GitHub uses by default a [git merge `--log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge--mltmsggt), where a a shortlog of the commits being merged will be appended to the specified message.

That is a convention you would find on the repository for Git itself, where:

- one merge commit (like [74ae065](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74ae0652c4736629db9c97f7a3ac7cebedaeae10)) has a fairly detailed subject message
- one commit from the merged branch (like [6163f3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6163f3f1a4288a6a17d2e3cdee4391b25ef09edd)) has a *huge* detailled message.

Comment: Is there a way to change Github's default?

Comment: @DavidGiven Not that I know of, as it is entirely managed on GitHub side, without any user setting/configuration I am aware of.